# Find definition of ENV $HISTFILE

Tags: grep, find, command-history

I want to find the place where histfile is definied:

```
echo $HISTFILE
/home/user/.bash_history
```

I thought it has to be defined in some profile- or rc file but I couldn't find it.

```
sudo grep --include=\*{rc,profile}\* -rnw '/' -e "*bash_history*"
```

How can I find the definition of ENV histfile?

Answer (score 0):

That's just the [default value](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html) for `HISTFILE`.

> When the shell starts up, the history is initialized from the file named by the `HISTFILE` variable (default `~/.bash_history`).

It looks like you've overwritten your `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you may want to get the normal behavior back by adding `shell_session_history_check;` to the beginning of it. Add `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` to the top of your profile to see the default value for it (`shell_session_history_check; terminal_update_cwd`).

Once you do that, `HISTFILE` will be over-written in this function (run `declare -f shell_session_history_check` to see the function call to `shell_session_history_enable`):

```
$ declare -f shell_session_history_enable
shell_session_history_enable () 
{ 
    ( umask 077;
    /usr/bin/touch "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW" );
    HISTFILE="$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW";
    SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=1
}
```

This will create a file in `.bash_sessions` to store a log of each session separately. More on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/397uep/changes_to_bash_sessions_and_terminal_in_el/):

> (~/.bash_sessions/) is used to store HISTFILE's and .session files
>   that are unique to sessions. If $BASH_SESSION or $TERM_SESSION_ID is
>   set upon launching the shell (i.e. if Terminal is resuming from a
>   saved state), the associated HISTFILE is merged into the current one,
>   and the .session file is ran. Session saving is facilitated by means
>   of an EXIT trap being set for a function bash_update_session_state.

Comment: some related info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450492/what-does-shell-session-history-check-do/450493#450493